UWP project not able to connect to localhost
I have an app built on Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. It's designed for Android and UWP. It was running fine on both systems but since yesterday I can't connect to my Xampp localhost server whenever I run on the UWP emulator. On the Android emulator everything is fine and also on physical Android devices.
I was trying to connect to my localhost server so that I can retrieve the data to login.

By default, UWP cannot access localhost. For security reasons, a UWP app that is installed in the standard manner is not allowed to make network calls to the device it is installed on.
You can disable the feature in Visual Studio debug settings, or follow this document How to enable loopback and troubleshoot network isolation (Windows Runtime apps).
For more information, please refer to this thread Can't see localhost from UWP app
